# Production environment breaks fetch method

Tags: reactjs, express, hosting, fetch-api, cloudflare

## Background

### **Target State**

I want to provide a service which utilises OpenAI's chatbot API, so that my users can

### **Setup**

Frontend: React.js app built with Vite. Deployed successfully on Cloudflare pages.
Backend: Node.js app utilising 3rd parties: Express, OpenAI, and Airtable. Successfully deployed on render.com.

### **Problem**

I am unable to receive responses from OpenAI's API, when the frontend is in Production.

### **When it does work**

Whats strange to me is that the responses to questions are successfully received when questions are submitted from a non-production frontend. This means that when I've ran `npm run dev`, it works as expected. Also when i ran `npm run build` then `npm run preview`, it still works.

However, when I deploy the frontend on Cloudflare successfully, the API does not return responses.

## Errors

When I try to submit a question in production, I receive the following 2 errors in Console:

1. [Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PfHM.png)
2. [Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNpmp.png)

The errors are pointing to this code block:

```
const u = async i=>{
        if (i.key === "Enter")
            try {
                r(!0);
                const s = {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        prompt: e
                    })
                }
                  , c = await fetch("/api/ask", s);
                if (!c.ok)
                    throw new Error("Something went wrong");
                const {message: h} = await c.json();
                o(h)
            } catch (s) {
                console.error(s, "err")
            } finally {
                r(!1)
            }
    }
```

The above code is the code in the 'dist' file that was created on build.

Also, in Console / Network / Response, I get: `Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier`.

### Source Code

frontend/app.jsx:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import lens from "./assets/lens.png";
import loadingGif from "./assets/loading.gif";


function App() {
  const [prompt, updatePrompt] = useState(undefined);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (prompt != null && prompt.trim() === "") {
      setAnswer(undefined);
    }
  }, [prompt]);

  const sendPrompt = async (event) => {
    if (event.key !== "Enter") {
      return;
    }

    try {
      setLoading(true);

      const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ prompt }),
      };

      const res = await fetch("/api/ask", requestOptions);

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
      }

      const { message } = await res.json();
      setAnswer(message);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err, "err");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1 className="h1">Hi, I'm the AI Tutor</h1>
      <h2 className="h2">Ask me anything!</h2>
      <div className="app-container">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="spotlight__input"
            placeholder="What do you want to know?"
            disabled={loading}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: loading ? `url(${loadingGif})` : `url(${lens})`,
            }}
            onChange={(e) => updatePrompt(e.target.value)}
            onKeyDown={(e) => sendPrompt(e)}
            />
            <text className="text">Press enter to submit your question to our AI Tutor</text>
        <div className="spotlight__wrapper">
          <div className="spotlight__answer">{answer && <p>{answer}</p>}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

backend/index.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.post("/ask", async (req, res) => {
  const prompt = req.body.prompt;

  try {
    if (prompt == null) {
      throw new Error("Uh oh, no prompt was provided");
    }

    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "text-davinci-003",
      prompt,
      max_tokens: 64,
    });

    const completion = response.data.choices[0].text;

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: completion,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}!!`));
```

backend/package.json

```
{
  "name": "custom_chat_gpt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "airtable": "^0.11.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "openai": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried Googling for answers but could find solutions. I found this difficult to debug because the difference appears to be between local and production environments, and backend methods and hosting are not a strength of mine.

Comment: How do you serve the frontend app in production? Is your server running?

Comment: The server is hosted on Render.com here: https://ai-bot-backend.onrender.com. This returns 'cannot GET /', however, I believe this is not an issue, because it does successfully serve my frontend when frontend is started locally.